# Repeat Fade Effect not working

Tags: ios, uitableview, uiview, uiviewanimation, uiviewanimationtransition

Following is my code, Used for showing some fade effect while adding the table on a sub view. Problem is that code works for the first time. After adding table, when I hit close the Sub view button table is removed. But when I hit the Button to add table again on subview fade effect doesn't work fine

```
 double delayInSeconds2 = 0.1;

        dispatch_time_t popTime2 = dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, (int64_t)(delayInSeconds2 * NSEC_PER_SEC));
        dispatch_after(popTime2, dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^(void){


            self.otlTableRightView.frame=CGRectMake(100, 68, 300, 378);
            [self.otlTableRightView setAlpha:0.0];
            [self.otlRightFromView addSubview:self.otlTableRightView];


            [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:nil];
            [UIView setAnimationDuration:1.2];

            self.otlTableRightView.frame=CGRectMake(43, 68, 300, 378);

            [UIView commitAnimations];


            [UIView animateWithDuration:2.0 delay:0.0 options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseInOut animations:^{
                [self.otlTableRightView setAlpha:0.0];
            }completion:^(BOOL done){

            }];

        });
```

and I am using

```
[self.otlTableRightView removeFromSuperview];
```

to remove my table from my sub view

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some search, Finally I found something that works in my case. Here, **otlTableRightView** is the outlet for my **UItableView**

```
            self.otlTableRightView.alpha = 0;
            [UIView beginAnimations:@"fade in" context:nil];
            [UIView setAnimationDuration:2.0];
            self.otlTableRightView.alpha = 1.0;
            [UIView commitAnimations];
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want repeat animation you shouldn't `removeFromSuperview` your subview! Then all the repeat method does not matter.

You also may consider simpler solution for that kind of behavior:

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:0.5
                      delay:0.0
                    options:UIViewAnimationOptionAutoreverse | UIViewAnimationOptionRepeat | UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseInOut
                 animations:^{
                     [self.otlTableRightView setAlpha:0.0];
                 }
                 completion:^(BOOL done){
                [self.otlTableRightView setAlpha:2.0];
            }];
```

As you can see in option you can add multiple parameters.

Comment: UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseInOut is not working but other two options you mentioned are working properly

Answer (score 0):

To remove your table view with fade effect try this..Hope it wold work.

```
> [UIView animateWithDuration:1.0
>                       delay:0.0
>                     options: UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseInOut
>                  animations:^{
>                      [self.otlTableRightView setAlpha:0.0];
>                  }
>                  completion:^(BOOL done){
>                 [self.otlTableRightView removeFromSuperview];
>             }];
```